# Generic enum iterator java

Tags: java, generics, enums, java-8

**My Enum**

```
public enum ExamStausEnum {

    RESULTAWAITED("Result Awaiting"), 
    PASSED("Passed"), 
    FAILED("Failed");

    private String value;

    ExamStausEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

**Generic Iterator Enum**

```
static <E extends Enum <E>> void foo(Class<E> elemType) {
    for (E e : java.util.EnumSet.allOf(elemType)) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Result :

```
RESULTAWAITED
PASSED
FAILED
```

How can I print the constructor values ?

```
Result Awaiting
Passed
Failed
```

Comment: You mean `System.out.println(e.getValue())`?

Comment: @khelwood, but this is generic for all enums, and getValue is for this enum called ExamStausEnum

Comment: Can you override `toString()` on your enum?

Comment: you cannot do it generically. If you have a couple enums with value field, you can get that field using reflection.

Comment: @khelwood yes ! want same result

Comment: I dont have time to write an answer, but in essence the enum needs to `implements Valuable` where the `Valuable` interface defines `getValue()`

Answer (score 6):

It’s unavoidable to add another parameter to have an abstraction of the `getValue()` call:

```
static <E extends Enum <E>> void foo(Class<E> elemType, Function<? super E, ?> f) {
    for(E e : java.util.EnumSet.allOf(elemType)) {
        System.out.println(f.apply(e));
    }
}
```

Then, you may it invoke for arbitrary `enum` types not necessarily having that method, e.g.

```
foo(Thread.State.class, Object::toString);
```

or for your specific `enum` having the method:

```
foo(ExamStausEnum.class, ExamStausEnum::getValue);
```

Even more use cases are possible:

```
foo(Thread.State.class, Enum::name);
```

or

```
foo(ExamStausEnum.class, Enum::ordinal);
```

---

Of course, you may also let your `ExamStausEnum` type override the `toString()` method, eliminating the need for `foo` to call the `getValue()` method.

Answer (score 1):

the more foreward way is to create an *interface* declaring the `getValue()` method implemented by all your enums.

```
interface EnumWithValue{
   @JsonValue
   String getValue();
}

public enum ExamStausEnum implements EnumWithValue {

    RESULTAWAITED("Result Awaiting"), 
    PASSED("Passed"), 
    FAILED("Failed");

    private String value;

    ExamStausEnum(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

then you can cast your enum in `foo`:

```
static <E extends Enum <E>> void foo(Class<E> elemType) {
    for (E e : java.util.EnumSet.allOf(elemType)) {
        System.out.println(((EnumWithValue)e).getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: I’d rather change the declaration to `<E extends Enum<E>&EnumWithValue> void foo(Class<E> elemType)` instead of inserting a type cast that can fail at runtime.

Comment: I think your suggestion will also fail at runtime in the same situation...

Comment: When you use the declaration `<E extends Enum<E>&EnumWithValue>`, the compiler will already reject `Class` objects of enums not implementing `EnumWithValue`. With your code, you will not even get a warning when passing a wrong type.